# Writing a generic functor instance across type constructors?

Tags: haskell, types, functor

I'm learning basic type classes and have written my own implementation of `functor` for my type `Test a` (behaves just like `Maybe`):

```
data Test a = Test a | Emp

class FC c a where
  t :: (a -> b) -> c a -> c b

instance FC Test a where
  t f (Test a) = Test (f a) 
  t f (Emp) = Emp

instance FC Maybe a where
  t f (Just a) = Just (f a) 
  t f (Nothing) = Nothing
```

Is it possible to implement something like:

```
instance FC c where
  t f (c v) = c (f v)
```

Error:

```
Parse error in pattern: c
```

In other words, abstract away the type constructor, replace with `c` and `v`, therefore creating a general instance that can be applied to any value with a context?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you've learned, `c a` is not a syntactically valid pattern. But reading your question instead as a feature proposal: How would that work? Not every `Functor` has a single-element constructor which can be mapped over according to your pattern. Some examples:

```
data Pair a = Pair a a  -- more than one element
instance Functor Pair where
    fmap f (Pair x y) = Pair (f x) (f y)

data Proxy a = Proxy  -- no elements
instance Functor Proxy where
    fmap f Proxy = Proxy

newtype Cont r a = Cont { runCont :: (a -> r) -> r }  -- element appears in a double-negative position
instance Functor (Cont r) where
    fmap f (Cont g) = Cont (g . (. f))
```

In any case, I don't think the idea of a "generic instance" really makes sense. The instance is where you put your type-specific code. (It has to go somewhere!)

If you want to exert less effort in writing `Functor` instances you can use GHC's `DeriveFunctor` extension.

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveFunctor #-}

data Pair a = Pair a a deriving Functor

data Proxy a = Proxy deriving Functor

newtype Cont r a = Cont { runCont :: (a -> r) -> r } deriving Functor
```

Answer (score 4):

You can do something very generic using `GHC.Generic`. Here is an incomplete example for a generic `FC` class definition (this is exactly what the [generic-deriving](https://github.com/dreixel/generic-deriving/blob/master/src/Generics/Deriving/Functor.hs) package does):

First some extensions and importing the generics machinery

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DefaultSignatures #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveGeneric #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators #-}

import GHC.Generics
```

Then we define a class which mirrors your `FC` but we only have instances for the generic types

```
class GFC c where
  gt :: (a -> b) -> c a -> c b

-- Constructors without arguments (Empty)
instance GFC U1 where
  gt _ U1 = U1

-- Constructors where the parameter appears (Test a)
instance GFC Par1 where
  gt f (Par1 a) = Par1 (f a)

-- Sums (| in datatype definitions)
instance (GFC f, GFC g) => GFC (f :+: g) where
  gt f (L1 a) = L1 (gt f a)
  gt f (R1 a) = R1 (gt f a)

-- Meta information wrapper
instance GFC f => GFC (M1 i c f) where
  gt f (M1 a) = M1 (gt f a)

-- ... the rest of the instances for the generic types here.
-- But these 4 instances are all that is needed for your `Test` type.
```

Then you can have a default implementation for `FC` based on the above "generic" `FC`:

```
class FC c where
  t :: (a -> b) -> c a -> c b
  default -- DefaultSignatures allows us to do this
    t :: (Generic1 c, GFC (Rep1 c)) => (a -> b) -> c a -> c b
  t f = to1 . gt f . from1 
  -- turn something with Generic1 into its generic representation, 
  -- use the generic `gt` and then turn it back into its actual 
  -- representation

data Test a = Test a | Empty
  deriving (Generic1, Show)

instance FC Test
```

And it works:

```
GHCI> t (==0) (Test (1 :: Int))
Test False
```

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know this is not possible, simply because there can be multiple constructors and it is unknown whether a generic constructor `Foo` can take any attribute as type.

Say for instance you have a type called:

```
data Foo a = Bar Int | Qux a
```

Now it means you cannot abstract away the constructor. As long as it is `Qux`, there is no problem, but `Bar` always expects an `Int` and thus will error. Since you here define an `instance` over any kind of `c`, there will be cases where this does not work. Note furthermore that the `c` in your `instance` declaration has nothing to do with the `c` in your definition of `t`. In other words: constructors can imply type constraints so you cannot simply factor them out.

A remark on your question is that you can generalize both you `class` defintion and `instance`:

```
class FC c where
  t :: (a -> b) -> c a -> c b

instance FC Test where
  t f (Test a) = Test (f a) 
  t f Emp = Emp
```

So you can remove the `a` in the `class` definition. This is not equivalent with your questions since here you say that it can work for any `a`. Whereas when you define a class `FC c a` you can decide for which `a`s you want implement an `instance`.